# missing route data when switching between sibling routes

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have a component-tree which, if simplified, looks like this:

```
                           parent
                           /    \    
                       childA   childB
                                   \
                                 childBC
```

From `childA` I wish to go to `childBC` and I do it like this:

`// from childA: 
this.router.navigate(['childB', 'childBC', someVeryImportantData], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });`

And in `childBC` I do this:

`this.route.data.subscribe(data => {......});`

When i do this, i get the following error: 
[image]

However: neither `ChildB`or `childBC` gets instantiated so the error happens before all this.

Can someone please tell me what is going on here?

Comment: Don't know the actual problem, just looking the error, cannot read `data of null`. you have `Router` injected in `childBC` as `route` right?

Comment: I do. And i think it is the router somewhere that doesnt get instantiated.  But I don't Think it's in childBC